# dplyr how to count cycles in the records

Tags: r, dplyr

For example, if I have records like:

```
A B
1 2
2 3
3 1
1 2
2 1
```

Let's say one cycle is from 1 (to 2 to 3) back to 1,so I need my data frame to be like

```
No.    A B
cycle1 1 2
cycle1 2 3
cycle1 3 1
cycle2 1 2
cycle2 2 1
```

Or a better way for me, I just need to record the time the same record appears, like

```
Time    A B
Time1   1 2
Time1   2 3
Time1   3 1
Time2   1 2
Time1   2 1
```

I need to do this because I have to use summarize function in dplyr to do calculation but I cannot group data by A and B directly. The order of the data is also important.

Comment: `cumsum(dat$A==1)` ? I'm a bit confused with your second example why the second `2` in `A` doesn't become `Time2` as well.

Comment: @thelatemail i think op mean `group(A,B)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

```
library(zoo)
T1=which(df$A==1)
T2=1:length(T1)
T2=paste('cycle',T2 )
df$No=NA
df$No[T1]=T2
df$No=na.locf(df$No)
df
  A B      No
1 1 2 cycle 1
2 2 3 cycle 1
3 3 1 cycle 1
4 1 2 cycle 2
5 2 1 cycle 2
#the reason: keep the row Id with the calculation 


library(dplyr)
df%>%group_by(A,B)%>%mutate(Time=paste('Time',row_number()))

      A     B   Time
  <int> <int>  <chr>
1     1     2 Time 1
2     2     3 Time 1
3     3     1 Time 1
4     1     2 Time 2
5     2     1 Time 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an augmented 'diff' variable. c(NA  , diff (your_var)). Within a sequence group this will be 1. Set your group to change at  the logical falsity of that proposition. (My first iteration on the algorithm wasn't quite correct so modified it slightly.)

```
dat %>% as_tibble() %>% mutate(G = cumsum( c(-1, diff(A)) < 0 ) )
# A tibble: 5 x 3
      A     B     G
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     2     1
2     2     3     1
3     3     1     1
4     1     2     2
5     2     1     2

dat %>% as_tibble() %>% mutate(G = paste0( "time", cumsum( c(-1, diff(A)) < 0 ) ))
# A tibble: 5 x 3
      A     B     G
  <int> <int> <chr>
1     1     2 time1
2     2     3 time1
3     3     1 time1
4     1     2 time2
5     2     1 time2
```

One could also test for A=1, but then sequences like 1,2,3,2,3,4 would not get properly split.